# any gem available that will pull out the get and post parameters ofsource code that I've got using net/http?

Tags: ruby, parsing, rubygems

I am pulling the source code of a webpage using net/http and I was wondering if there was anyway to parse out the get and post parameters so that they can be listed?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

GET and POST parameters are in the HTTP header, not the HTML source. So the answer is no, you can't get it from the source, unless you know that the information has been somehow encoded in HTML, or can do that yourself.

However, any GET or POST parameters would have been sent by your Net::HTTP code, so you can print those out yourself.

Comment: What I mean is there any way to auto complete forms etc. to view all of the user input on a web application?

Comment: @tom, are you saying you have a back-end process that accepts a form post, and needs to fetch the original form and merge it with the post params? In any case, I think you need to edit your question and add additional detail.